# jQuery .click( foo() ) unexpected behavior

Tags: javascript, jquery, webforms, jquery-events

Today I came across a bug in my web app regarding form search submit function (in js) and a button click action in jQuery.

I have a form that has the action `submitEmpSearch()` attached to it.  This is embedded in the html of the form as it's `onSubmit` action. There is also a search button associated with the form with an `onclick` event `submitEmpSearch()`.  I was making an attempt to clear out embedded javascript from the templates in favor of jQuery calls.  In an included jQuery call I had the call `$('#search-button').click( submitEmpSearch() )` inside my `$(document).ready` group.

From my previous experience with the `.click()` function, I expected this to have the same functionality as the embedded `onclick` attribute provided.  However, instead, it gave the page an infinite loop of (apparently) clicking the button as soon as it loaded!

Now, previously, I always passed a `function() {}` pattern.  I had never passed in a predefined function before. Is this some kind of gotcha in the jQuery <del>language</del> framework?  Or is there something else I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

jQuery is not a language.  [JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74884/good-javascript-books) is the language.  You're passing the *result* of the function, when you want to pass the function itself:

It should be:

```
$('#search-button').click(submitEmpSearch)
```

In JavaScript, functions can be passed as values.  However, `submitEmpSearch()` is the return value of a call to the function, as one would expect from other languages.

Comment: Just to say that `jQuery is not a language.`
is well intended but awfully misguided :)

Comment: @Christian, I disagree.  People who think jQuery is a programming language tend to neglect to learn the real language they're working in.  Then, they make mistakes like this.

Comment: That's why I said it's "well intended", because this kind of syntax works the same for other languages out there. In PHP, for example, you pass the function name as a string. Other languages do the same as jquery(javascript), including c++ and delphi.

Comment: This isn't really a mistake due to lack of jquery knowledge.  Same exact mistake could've easily been made within the standard JavaScript syntax if jquery wasn't even used.

Comment: @Christian, again, the language is JavaScript.  I agree other languages behave similar to JavaScript in this regard (though PHP only recently got true closures).  @Kon, I said the opposite of that; it's a mistake due to not learning "the real language", JavaScript.

Comment: I don't think recommending him to get a book on JavaScript holds any value and comes across abrasive. I think you should get rid of that first sentence and just add a "btw ... jQuery isn't a language" ... /two cents

Comment: @Chad.  Agreed, but my experience with javascript is limited. I'm always open to a good reference book.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of

```
$('search-button').click( submitEmpSearch() )
```

use just

```
$('#search-button').click( submitEmpSearch )
```

or

```
$('#search-button').click( function(){submitEmpSearch();} )
```

Also if the 'search-button' is a class you have to add a "." (dot) before it. If it is an id you have to add "#".
See my examples.

Answer (score 1):

Aha!

You should pass the function by reference, not call the function and pass its result:

```
function handler(){
    // ...
}
jQuery('.something').click(handler()); // <- wrong
jQuery('.something').click( handler ); // <- right
```

Comment: I swear I tried that after checking the jQuery docs: passing the reference to the function makes sense, but I don't think it solved anything.  I was, however, pair programming and not the one in the driver's seat.  I'm having it checked again.

Comment: aahh, the wonders of group programming and missing things that should be obvious.  tried it, fixed the bug, lost the button functionality.  Forgot to actually add the id to the button.  *facepalm*

Answer (score 0):

Change from:

```
$('search-button').click(submitEmpSearch())
```

to:

```
$('search-button').click(submitEmpSearch)
```

This way instead of executing submitEmpSearch() and passing its return value to the click(), you're passing the delegate to the click().

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
$('#search-button').click(function(){
    submitEmpSearch();
});
```

Comment: There's no reason for the extra layer of indirection.

Comment: It would work, but it's not answering the question really.  Though I wouldn't have down voted.